# How to set a transparent background for Vim with "true color" enabled?

Tags: vim, color-scheme, vim-syntax-highlighting, viml

I've enabled *true colors* for Vim with success using:

```
set t_8f=\[[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum
set t_8b=\[[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum
set termguicolors
```

(check `:h xterm-true-color` for more information)

I have then enabled a true color colorscheme to try the new setting, like:

```
set background=dark
colors deep-space
```

(https://github.com/tyrannicaltoucan/vim-deep-space)

Previously when using 256 colors I was able to get a transparent background by:

```
hi! Normal ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
hi! NonText ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
```

Now, this is not working anymore and I don't know any alternative. Is it possible to get transparent background with Vim under `termguicolors`?

### UPDATE

I've opened an issue on Vim's issue tracker: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/981

Comment: Which version of Vim you are usign?

Comment: @ArslanAli if you check the referred issue, there's no version of Vim that works properly at the moment. A patch must be applied or use NeoVim instead.